# How to convert a string to hyphen-conjoined words in JavaScript (& regex?)?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Let's say I have a string of text:

```
The quick brown fox jumped over 8 or 9 lazy dogs
```

How would you convert this to lower case hyphen-conjoined words like this?

```
the-quick-brown-fox-jumped-over-8-or-9-lazy-dogs
```

I assume it requires some kind of regex to convert it correctly?

Answer (score 15):

```
str.replace(/ +/g, '-').toLowerCase();
```

Comment: This will convert multiple spaces into one hyphen.

Comment: @ideal That's the idea. If that's not what's wanted, just remove the `+`.

Comment: kudos for adding the lower case - obviously this is meant for class naming.

Comment: Prefer `/\s+/g` to match more whitespace types

Answer (score 10):

Use `\s` for a space character in a regular expression, add the `g` flag so it replaces all occurrences, and call `toLowerCase()` to make the string lowercase:

```
str.replace(/\s/g, "-").toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Your smiley `"-"` is more stressed out than my smiley `'-'`. `^_-`

Comment: This will also match tabs and linefeeds.

Comment: @idealmachine Yes, any whitespace character.

Comment: Prefer `/\s+/g` so we don't get multiple `-` when typing multiple spaces. Similar to the other answer but matching all whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Or this:
    "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".split(" ").join("-");

Comment: Sorry, forgot that you wanted it lowercase:

"The quick brown fox jumped over 8 or 9 lazy dogs".split(" ").join("-").toLowerCase();